# How is 0th law of thermodynamics possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, equilibrium

If a body of gas A (say at $25\ ^\circ \rm C$) is brought in contact with another body of gas B (say at $10\ ^\circ \rm C$), then B absorbs heat from A until they both reach $17.5\ 
 ^\circ \rm C$ and are in thermodynamical equilibrium.

When a body of gas C (say at $15\ ^\circ \rm C$) is brought in contact with A, C absorbs heat from A until they both reach $20\ ^\circ \rm C$. So now if B is brought in contact with C, heat should flow from C to B right?

Comment: @Triatticus Please do not answer questions in the comments. If you have an answer, write it up! Thanks!

Comment: It's not an answer at all really, because any answer will need to address why this does/doesn't concern the zeroth law. I should have asked why they think that this is a problem for that specific law

Comment: [Related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/492681/179151)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to follow your sequence. It was not clear to me from the description if at the end you were bringing B together with C before or after they each were each in contact with A. But it turned out not to  matter as either way heat will flow from C to B. If I followed you correctly, the sequences are as shown in the diagram below. The equilibrium temperatures you assigned to B and C after initial contact with A assumes they have the same mass and specific heat as A.

The thing is I don't see that your description has anything to do with the Zeroth Law of thermodynamics, which states:

*If two thermodynamic systems are in thermal equilibrium with a third one, then they are in thermal equilibrium with each other.*

At the end of your sequence B and C are in thermal equilibrium with each other, but neither is in thermal equilibrium with the third, A, either the original A, or the A after contact with each of B and C. Perhaps you could elaborate further at to how this applies to the title of your post.

For a detailed discussion of the Zeroth Law see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth_law_of_thermodynamics

> Thanks for the answer! What I meant to ask was: after the first two
>   steps, B and C were in thermal equilibrium with A but they were not in
>   equilibrium with each other. Isn't this against the 0th law?

But there is no reason why they should be. Neither B nor C were *initially* in thermal equilibrium with A.

To apply the law to your bodies, it would say that if B is in thermal equilibrium with (the same temperature as) A and C is in thermal equilibrium with (the same temperature as) A, then B is in thermal equilibrium with (the same temperature as) C. But that's not what you have.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I meant to ask was: after the first two steps, B and C were in thermal equilibrium with A but they were not in equilibrium with each other. Isn't this against the 0th law?

Comment: @KarthikeyaKaza I have updated my post to answer your follow up comment.

Comment: Thanks Bob. My textbook says this about the 0th law : Imagine two systems A and B, separated by an adiabatic wall, while each is in contact with a third system C, via a conducting wall [Fig. 12.2(a)]. The states of the systems (i.e., their macroscopic variables) will change until both A and B come to thermal equilibrium with C. After this is achieved, suppose that the adiabatic wall between A and B is replaced by a conducting wall and C is insulated from A and B by an adiabatic wall. It is found that the states of A and B change no further i.e. they are found to be in thermal equilibrium.

Comment: @KarthikeyaKaza That's certainly true. After the two systems A and B are in contact with C via a conducting wall, then both A and B will eventually be in thermal equilibrium with C, which means temperature A is the same as C and temperature B is the same as C. Now if the adiabatic wall  between A and B is removed, this allows for the possibility of heat transfer between A and B. But since the temperatures of A and B are the same, no further change to either occurs because heat will not flow if thermal equilibrium exists. Heat is defined as energy transfer SOLELY due to temperature difference.

Comment: So when A and B are in contact with C, the heat energy of the three systems combined gets distributed such that all three are in thermal equilibrium? If so, thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @KarthikeyaKaza Almost. The key is that the two systems A and B that are in contact with C via the conducting wall AT THE SAME TIME. That being the case, C can only have one final temperature when contacting A and B, and that final temperature has to be the same as the final temperature of A and B. In your example I believe A is in contact with B and C separately, so the final temperature of C is different for each separate contact. Check out the following Hyperphysics link on the law: http://www.hyperphysics.de/hyperphysics/hbase/thermo/thereq.html